# Apache giving pages as downloads rather than displaying them

Tags: apache, lamp, mediawiki

I just installed MediaWiki on a website and I am having some problems.

Whenever I go to "www.something.com/wikidir" the server gives me the PHP index file as an unnamed download instead of displaying it.

However, if I go to "www.something.com/wikidir/index.php" everything works as expected.

I'm not familiar with Apache and was wondering if someone could tell me how to fix this or point me in the right direction?

I'm using a LAMP stack and Mediawiki 1.7.1 (old I know).

In my .htacces file I have:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like Apache (or PHP?) is serving the page as an application/octet-stream. You can check this by looking at the response headers on the non-index.php page. Firefox can do this using the Web Developer Toolbar > Information > View Response Headers. Look for "Content-Type"

Or, Does the non-index.php link work in IE? Does it go straight to download in Firefox (or another browser)? If the answer is yes, that's the problem.

How to fix it is more complex because there could be a bunch of different things that are causing this. My guess is that's it's an Apache config issue.

***Edit***
Check your .htaccess file. Make sure it's readable by Apache. I bet that's the issue.

Comment: Also, try checking what your "DefaultType" is set to in Apache. If it's application/octet-stream, that's another possbile problem. Should probably something like text/plain.

Comment: It does indeed work in IE but not Chrome... Do I just add the DefaultType in my local .htaccess folder? I already checked that it is readable by Apache

Comment: Your .htaccess suggestion worked out. I added an AddType and that worked. I was having problems still afterwards though because I forgot to clear my cache. *doh*

Comment: After I re-read this, it might not be the type. :( When you use the non-index.php page, what file is downloaded? Is it the same as the index.php page? Maybe it's an issue with the order the files are being processed by Apache? (There are a whole bunch of possibilities, here... I'm just guessing now)

***Edit***
Nevermind! Glad it worked!